# Does std::string find require that pos be less than the string size?

Tags: c++, string, stl, stdstring

Just reading 21.3.6.1 basic_string::find - and there is no mention that the pos argument be within bounds of the string itself.

> 21.3.6.1 basic_string::find
>
> size_type find(const basic_string& str,
>   size_type pos = 0) const;
>
> 1 Effects: Determines the lowest position xpos, if possible, such that
>   both of the following conditions obtain:
>
> — pos <= xpos and xpos + str.size() <= size();
>
> — at(xpos+I) == str.at(I) for all elements I of the string controlled
>   by str.
>
> 2 Returns: xpos if the function can determine such a value for xpos.
>   Otherwise, returns npos.

I am reading this correctly?

Comment: To be fair you could just try...

Comment: @DrG: The behaviour you would observe in that experiment would tell you nothing about whether that behaviour was well-defined/portable/etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wording of the spec does not require that `pos` be less than the length of the string.  If `pos` is greater than the length of the string, then the first part of condition (1) cannot be satisfied, because if `pos <= xpos`, then `xpos + str.size() <= size()` can never be true.  As a result, by clause (2), the function will return `npos`.  Consequently, if the index is out of range, the behavior of the function is still perfectly well-defined.

Hope this helps!